# ZF2 RoleUserBridge: not getting inserted after registering

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser, bjyauthorize

Trying to use `RoleUserBridge` so that when registering using `zfcuser`, `user_role_linker` database table will get updated automatically.

I have done the following:

> 1) successfully copied the directory in vendor. 
>   2) copy linker.config.php to config/autoconfig directory

But, registering a new user using zfcuser doesn't add a table entry to user_role_linker database.

I checked the `user_role_mapper` function inside `RoleUserBridge/Module.php`'s factories

```
'factories' => array(

            'user_role_mapper' => function ($sm) {
                $options = $sm->get('zfcuser_module_options');
                $mapper = new Mapper\RoleMapper();
                $mapper->setDbAdapter($sm->get('zfcuser_zend_db_adapter'));

                $entityClass = $options->getUserEntityClass();

                $mapper->setEntityPrototype(new $entityClass);
                $mapper->setHydrator(new \ZfcUser\Mapper\UserHydrator());
                return $mapper;
            },
        )
```

This gets called (I put a `die()` to test).

Next, I put a die in `RoleUserBridge\Mapper\RoleMapper.php`'s insert function. But, this never gets called.

So, what's happening is that the factory is creating an instance, but the insert function never gets executed.

```
public function insert($entity, $tableName = null, HydratorInterface $hydrator = null)
{
    $options = $this->getOptions();
    $tableName = $options['user_role_linker'];
    $result = parent::insert($entity, $tableName, $hydrator);
    var_dump($entity);
    var_dump($hydrator);
    var_dump($result);
    die();

    return $result;
}
```

Maybe I'm not linking something correctly...

My load order is:

```
'modules' => array(
    // loads all 3rd party modules first
    'ZfcBase',
    'ZfcUser',
    'ZfcAdmin',
    'BjyAuthorize',
    'RoleUserBridge',
    ...
```

Please advice!

edit on Nov 8th based on Rajeeb's feedback

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

    $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    //zfcuser_user_service --- provided by ZfcUser module
    $userService = $serviceManager->get('zfcuser_user_service');
    //handling "register.post" event
    $userService->getEventManager()->attach('register.post', 
        function(\Zend\EventManager\Event $e) use ($serviceManager) {
            //get user entity from event params
            $user = $e->getParam('user');
            //this is my own "userrole" service, you can target to "userrolelinker" service
            $userRoleService = $serviceManager->get('UserRole\Service\UserRoleService');
            //below line is actually calling the insert functionallity via service
            //if you would like can also be done by "mapper" class also without 
            //the involvement of "service" class 
                die('boo');
            $userRoleService->insertUserRole(array(
                'userId' => $user->getId(),
                'roleId' => 3 //my target role id for the new users
            ));
        }
    );
}
```

Cheers,

Justin

Comment: Did you enable the module in the application config file?

Comment: Hi Aydin! Thanks for the reply. I did enable the module (I just tried turning off my module and my user_role_mapper function inside RoleUserBridge/Module.php wouldn't be called). Can you suggest other elements that I might have overlooked?

Comment: Hmm, did you enable it after ZfcUser? If so I'll have a play on the weekend see if I can get it working

Comment: Hey Aydin, I did enable it after ZfcUser, this is the order.     'modules' => array(
        // loads all 3rd party modules first
        'ZfcBase',
        'ZfcUser',
        'ZfcAdmin',
        'BjyAuthorize',
        'RoleUserBridge', To better read the code, I have updated my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the onBootStrap part. Looking at the code of RoleUserBridge, it overrides the zfcuser module. In my RoleUserBridge/Module.php ,

```
  public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'zfcuser_user_service' => 'RoleUserBridge\Service\User',
        ),
        'factories' => array(

            'user_role_mapper' => function ($sm) {
                $options = $sm->get('zfcuser_module_options');
                $config = $sm->get('config');
                $mapper = new Mapper\RoleMapper($config);
                $mapper->setDbAdapter($sm->get('zfcuser_zend_db_adapter'));
                $entityClass = $options->getUserEntityClass();
                $mapper->setEntityPrototype(new $entityClass);
                $mapper->setHydrator(new \ZfcUser\Mapper\UserHydrator());
                return $mapper;
            },
        )
    );
}
```

the invokables part overrides zfcuser_user_service to use RoleUserBridge\Service\User , only this class makes use of the user_role_mapper. You can start debugging by making sure the User object you are using is indeed the roleuserbridge one, otherwise user_role_mapper won't be used.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Well Justin, everything is fine in this bridge module but lacking the documentation about how to actually execute the insert action. I have gone through the module on Github and found this. You have to actually make a call to the Service/Mapper insert function by handling the "register.post" event thrown by "zfcuser". Check out the code below.

This is my Application's "Module.php" class "bootstrap" event handler

```
    //----keep what was there before--------
    $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    //zfcuser_user_service --- provided by ZfcUser module
    $userService = $serviceManager->get('zfcuser_user_service');
    //handling "register.post" event
    $userService->getEventManager()->attach('register.post', 
            function(\Zend\EventManager\Event $e) use ($serviceManager) {
        //get user entity from event params
        $user = $e->getParam('user');
        //this is my own "userrole" service, you can target to "userrolelinker" service
        $userRoleService = $serviceManager->get('UserRole\Service\UserRoleService');
        //below line is actually calling the insert functionallity via service
        //if you would like can also be done by "mapper" class also without 
        //the involvement of "service" class 
        $userRoleService->insertUserRole(array(
            'userId' => $user->getId(),
            'roleId' => 3 //my target role id for the new users
        ));
    });
```

hope this will help you.
Also you may google handling zf2 events.

Comment: Hi Rajeeb! Thanks for the reply. I added this code to my onBootstrap handler in my Application Module.php class. But, it is not getting called... let me update my post to include my handler function.

Comment: Hi juworld! I think you are doing wrong below the line that says "//this is my own "userrole" service, you can target to "userrolelinker" service". So try using the relevant UserRoleLinker Service instance (that you are getting from DI                      as "$userRoleService = $serviceManager->get('UserRole\Service\UserRoleService');" ). This is what my personal class refers to you should try the Service Class that is inside "RoleUserBridge" module.